# Creating a Javascript moduleLibrary

Tags: javascript, facebook, module

I would like to know what are the best practises/methods in creating a custom Javascript module library, near-facebook like. The following doesn't work, but, in a way, outlines what I am attempting to do:

```
// MyApplication.js
(function(window,undefined){
    MyApplication.prototype = {
        init : function() {},
        // Example usage:
        api : function(uri, input) {
            // Return a parsed output on callback
        }
    };
    window.MyApplication = MyApplication;
})(window);

// Somewhere else

MyApplication.api('/path/to/something', {index : value}, function(output){
    // Return parsed output variable
});
```

I'm not looking for a third-party library which does my example, or something along the lines of jQueryMX which defines classes. The attempt is to create a stand alone library for use within "MyApplication".

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call that a "closure library", you're just trying to create a JavaScript "module". There's several ways to do it, I'd start by searching for JavaScript module patterns.